# Error when checking input: expected conv1d_57_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (152, 64)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_57_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (152, 64).

My code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(152,64)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainingMatrix, labelTraining, validation_data=(validationMatrix, labelValidation), epochs=3)
```

Variable description:

`trainingMatrix.shape = (152,64);` Lines are associated with samples and columns with features.

Is it a reshape problem?

Edit:

I made the changes below:

```
trainingMatrix = np.expand_dims(trainingMatrix, axis=3)
validationMatrix = np.expand_dims(validationMatrix, axis=3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainingMatrix, labelTraining, validation_data=(validationMatrix, labelValidation), epochs=3)
```

I get this new error: Error when checking target: expected dense_28 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

My Summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param    
=================================================================
conv1d_51 (Conv1D)           (None, 62, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_52 (Conv1D)           (None, 60, 64)            12352     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 60, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 30, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_16 (Flatten)         (None, 1920)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 100)               192100    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 404       
=================================================================
Total params: 205,112
Trainable params: 205,112
Non-trainable params: 0
```

New code and new error:

```
trainingMatrix = np.expand_dims(trainingMatrix, axis=0)
validationMatrix = np.expand_dims(validationMatrix, axis=0)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(152,64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_57: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

The solution below works, but the hit rate is too low. Does anyone recommend a configuration to improve? I am not achieving more than 20% accuracy. (using MLP I got 90%)

```
trainingMatrix = np.expand_dims(trainingMatrix, axis=3)
validationMatrix = np.expand_dims(validationMatrix, axis=3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainingMatrix, labelTraining, validation_data=(validationMatrix, labelValidation), epochs=1000)
```

My labelTraining is:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
...
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
...
0 0 0 1
```

Is it ok?

Comment: `152` is your number of samples right? In that case change your input shape to `input_shape=(64,)`. You are not supposed to give number of samples in input shape, Keras takes it automatically.

Comment: have you tried reshaping to 152,64,1 or 1,152,64?

Comment: @VivekMehta I changed the code following your suggestion, but i get other error:Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: @3NiGMa I get this error in both cases: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_6: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Follows the code working with 97% accuracy.

```
trainingMatrix = np.expand_dims(trainingMatrix, axis=3)
validationMatrix = np.expand_dims(validationMatrix, axis=3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainingMatrix, labelTraining, batch_size=batchSize, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(validationMatrix, labelValidation))
```

Answer (score 0):

**sparse_categorical_crossentropy  & categorical_crossentropy**

sparse_categorical_crossentropy:

> > > is used when target col contain multilabel  value and having single target column{It mean label can be greater than 1}

categorical_crossentropy

> > is used when target col contain mutilabel value and having muti target col{ it mean each col target value is binary}

**Replace sparse_categorical_crossentropy by categorical_crossentropy**